# Добавить текст к имеющемуся

Tags: c#

Занес текст в Body - но друг мне понадобилось добавить в него дополнительный текст из foreach - подскажите как желательно с Environment.NewLine

```
Message.Body = "Привет : " + Environment.UserName;
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach(DriveInfo dr in drives)
{
  Message.Body = dr.DriveType + " : " + dr.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
Message.Body = "Привет : " + Environment.UserName;
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach(DriveInfo dr in drives)
{
  Message.Body += (dr.DriveType + " : " + dr.Name);
}
```

Comment: Да.Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

C `Environment.NewLine`

```
Message.Body = "Привет : " + Environment.UserName;
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach(DriveInfo dr in drives)
{
  Message.Body += Environment.NewLine;
  Message.Body += (dr.DriveType + " : " + dr.Name);
}
```